# Redirect output to new date file in shell script

Tags: shell, perl

I have a shell script which call a Perl script which can run more than 20 hours .So if the process starts at 06/01 sometime it will end next day at 06/02. Below code i am using to write the output

```
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
logfile="$log_filename.${date}.log"
nohup run.pl >> $logfile 2>&1 &
```

So problem with this code i have having is it redirecting the output to the old date file even if the date change.

Is there any general solution that we pipe the stderr/stdout of the app to another program and it does the writes to a the rolling log file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write the data to a temporary file and rename it at the end of the run. I'd try to move all of the shell stuff into the Perl program so it can control choosing the file name and date format.